# Split the list when duplicate is found scala

Tags: list, scala, split, duplicates

I have a list of elements in Scala and I am looking for a way to split the list when a duplicate is found.

For example: `List(x,y,z,e,r,y,g,a)` would be converted to `List(List(x,y,z,e,r),List(y,g,a))`
or  `List(x,y,z,x,y,z)` to `List(x,y,z), List(x,y,z)`
and `List(x,y,z,y,g,x)` to `List(x,y,z), List(y,g,x)`

Is there a more efficient way than iterating and and cheking for every element separately?

Comment: Are you looking for a split at *every* duplicate or just the first?

Comment: There can be nothing more efficient that iterating and checking. How can you find out if the "next" element is  a duplicate without looking at it?

Comment: I am looking for every duplicate to split the list. At the end I want multiple lists containing no duplicates

Comment: @Kratos You should update your question, then, preferably with an example that shows, for instance, what you want to have happen with `List(x,y,z,x,y,z)` and `List(x,y,z,y,g,x)`.

Comment: Thanks.  But that's still ambiguous. Should `(a, b, c, c, d, e, a, f)` result in `(a, b, c), (c, d, ,e, a, f)` [no duplicates in either list] or `(a,b,c), (c, d, e), (a, f)` [no duplicates from any earlier list]

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul the moment a duplicate is found, I need the list to split. By that said and according to your example the fist case is what I want. when the initial list has no duplicates there is no need to split.

Comment: Thanks. Then @Nathaniel Ford's (for some odd reason downvoted) answer does what you want, I think (with some `.reverses` maybe)

Comment: Updated my answer, including the reverses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty `O(n)` using `O(n)` additional memory:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashSet
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

val list = List("x", "y", "z", "e", "r", "y", "g", "a", "x", "m", "z")

var result = new ListBuffer[ListBuffer[String]]()
var partition = new ListBuffer[String]()

list.foreach { i => 
    if (partition.contains(i)) {
        result += partition
        partition = new ListBuffer[String]()
    }
    partition += i
}

if (partition.nonEmpty) {
    result += partition
}
result
```

> ListBuffer(ListBuffer(x, y, z, e, r), ListBuffer(y, g, a, x, m, z))

Comment: for this list works fine. but it checks for every occurrence in the list, meaning that for a list: "x","y","z","e","r","y","g","a", "x", "m", "z" it will return
ListBuffer(ListBuffer(x, y, z, e, r), ListBuffer(y, g, a), ListBuffer(x, m), ListBuffer(z)). 
when I want it to return:
ListBuffer(ListBuffer(x, y, z, e, r), ListBuffer(y, g, a, x, m,z))

Comment: @Kratos ah... I misunderstood original problem. You can fix it easily by checking not if item is `lookup` but in `partition`. I'll edit my answer

Comment: yes. I just added a lookup.clear() under the partition creation in the first condition. Thank you @vsminkov. you really helped!

Comment: @Kratos no problem! I've dropped `lookup` completely and updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

This solution comes with a few caveats:

- I'm not making a claim as to 'performance', though I think it's better than `O(n^2)`, which is the brute-force.
- This is assuming you are splitting when you find a duplicate, where 'duplicate' means 'something that exists in the previous split'. I cheat a little by only checking the last segment. The reason is that I think it clarifies how to use [`foldLeft`](https://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2009/07/30/lots-and-lots-of-foldleft-examples/) a little, which is a natural way to go about this.
- Everything here is reversed, but maintains order. This can be easily corrected, but adds an additional `O(n)` (cumulative) call, and may not actually be needed (depending on what you're doing with it).

Here is the code:

```
def partition(ls: List[String]): List[ListSet[String]] = {
  ls.foldLeft(List(ListSet.empty[String]))((partitionedLists, elem:String) => {
    if(partitionedLists.head.contains(elem)) {
      ListSet(elem) :: partitionedLists
    } else {
      (partitionedLists.head + elem) :: partitionedLists.tail
    }
  })
}

partition(List("x","y","z","e","r","y","g","a"))
// res0: List[scala.collection.immutable.ListSet[String]] = List(ListSet(r, e, z, y, x), ListSet(a, g, y))
```

I'm using `ListSet` to get both the benefits of a `Set` and ordering, which is appropriate to your use case.

`foldLeft` is a function that takes an accumulator value (in this case the `List(ListSet.empty[String])`) and modifies it as it moves through the elements of your collection. If we structure that accumulator, as done here, to be a list of segments, by the time we're done it will have all the ordered segments of the original list.

Comment: This way I would have to rely on a listSet for keeping the order of the list. The implementation works though. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One statement tail-recursive version (but not very efficient because of the `contains` on the list)

```
var xs = List('x','y','z','e','r','y','g','a') 

def splitAtDuplicates[A](splits: List[List[A]], right: List[A]): List[List[A]] = 
  if (right.isEmpty)// done
    splits.map(_.reverse).reverse
  else if (splits.head contains right.head) // need to split here
    splitAtDuplicates(List()::splits, right)
  else // continue building current sublist
    splitAtDuplicates((right.head :: splits.head)::splits.tail, right.tail)
```

Speed it up with a `Set` to track what we've seen so far:

```
def splitAtDuplicatesOptimised[A](seen: Set[A], 
                                  splits: List[List[A]],
                                  right: List[A]): List[List[A]] = 
  if (right.isEmpty)
     splits.map(_.reverse).reverse 
  else if (seen(right.head))
     splitAtDuplicatesOptimised(Set(), List() :: splits, right)
  else
    splitAtDuplicatesOptimised(seen + right.head,
                              (right.head :: splits.head) :: splits.tail, 
                              right.tail)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will basically need to iterate with a look-up table. I can provide help with the follwoing immutable and functional tailrec implementation.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashSet    
import scala.annotation.tailrec

val list = List("x","y","z","e","r","y","g","a", "x", "m", "z", "ll")

def splitListOnDups[A](list: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  @tailrec
  def _split(list: List[A], cList: List[A], hashSet: HashSet[A], lists: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = {
    list match {
      case a :: Nil if hashSet.contains(a) => List(a) +: (cList +: lists)
      case a :: Nil => (a +: cList) +: lists
      case a :: tail if hashSet.contains(a) => _split(tail, List(a), hashSet, cList +: lists)
      case a :: tail => _split(tail, a +: cList, hashSet + a, lists)
    }
  }

  _split(list, List[A](), HashSet[A](), List[List[A]]()).reverse.map(_.reverse)
}

def splitListOnDups2[A](list: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  @tailrec
  def _split(list: List[A], cList: List[A], hashSet: HashSet[A], lists: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = {
    list match {
      case a :: Nil if hashSet.contains(a) => List(a) +: (cList +: lists)
      case a :: Nil => (a +: cList) +: lists
      case a :: tail if hashSet.contains(a) => _split(tail, List(a), HashSet[A](), cList +: lists)
      case a :: tail => _split(tail, a +: cList, hashSet + a, lists)
    }
  }

  _split(list, List[A](), HashSet[A](), List[List[A]]()).reverse.map(_.reverse)
}

splitListOnDups(list)
// List[List[String]] = List(List(x, y, z, e, r), List(y, g, a), List(x, m), List(z, ll))

splitListOnDups2(list)
// List[List[String]] = List(List(x, y, z, e, r), List(y, g, a, x, m, z, ll))
```

Comment: I think it is. Let the band play on!

Comment: how could I change the function so that I will have a split when a duplicate is found but not keeping history of what has been found before? For example in your result list array, the last three should be together, since they contain no duplicates.

Comment: Just reset the `hashSet` to empty `HashSet[A]()` on the recursive call in case of a duplicate. See `case a :: tail if hashSet.contains(a)` in `splitListOnDups2`